# Origin of counting Omer according to the Sephirot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, sefirat-ha-omer, sefirot-attributes

What is the origin of the association of each day of the Omer with a particular pair of Sephirot (Hesed sh'b'Hesed, etc.)?  I'm looking for the earliest textual mentions.

Comment: Probably no earlier than the 1500s.

Comment: I've seen sources in the Zohar that align the weeks with the Sephirot, but they don't go into the double alignment.  e.g. https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.97b.3?lang=bi